# StormCrawler: The URL Database Specifications

Tags: java, url, stormcrawler

I am quite new to **StormCrawler** - as I have been exploring the documentation, as well as the READMEs and additional resources, I have noticed that it is often referred to a **"URL database"** which should handle storing information concerning the the URLs from the run of the crawler (for example [here](http://stormcrawler.net/faq/)).

I have, however, not found anywhere of what type this database is, nor how to customize it or replace it with custom modules. I have been following the code and got to `IOOutputController`, which has some quite confusing methods and with the lack of docstrings, it is quite challenging to actually even determine the class responsible for handling this.

I would be very grateful for any guidance!

Thank you for your time, Matyáš

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most commonly used storage for the URLs in StormCrawler is Elasticsearch. This is illustrated in the [tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8kpJLPdhvLw). There are other ones available such as SQL or SOLR, see [enter link description here](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/tree/master/external); StormCrawler is not limited to a specific database.
In most cases, people just use an existing backend implementation such as the Elasticsearch one.

Comment: Thank you very much! Just one more question - which module (class) actually manages (handles) this? Thanks

Comment: you simply need to add the corresponding bolts and spouts in the topology as illustrated in the ES one